# Removal of elements from an array not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox

I have a set of checkboxes generated on select query from database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="grade_checkbox[]" class="grade_checkbox" value="1">
//value of checkbox is getting from database table.I have put value =1 as an example
```

On clicking of each checkboxes, I store the value of checkboxes into an array.

```
var selected_grades = [];
$(".grade_checkbox").click(function(){
  if(!$(this).is(":checked")
  {
     //remove the checkbox value from the array since it is unchecked
     if($.inArray($(this).val(),selected_grades)!==-1)
        {
            selected_grades.remove(selected_grades.indexOf($(this).val()));
        } 
  }
   selected_grades = $('input:checkbox:checked.grade_checkbox').map(function () {
                            return this.value;
                            }).get();
    console.log(selected_grades);
});
```

`selected_grades` is an array used for storing the checkbox values which are checked.

When I check each checkboxes,the array `selected_grades` is displayed in console with all checked checkbox values.

When I try to uncheck any checkboxes,I am actually trying to remove the element if exist from the above array.But I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: selected_grades.remove is not a function
```

I am unaware why this happens.

Comment: Use `array.splice()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: The answer by @palash gave the output for me.Thanks for your helping mentality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this using [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
selected_grades.splice(selected_grades.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);
```

**For example:-**

Let's say we want to remove `3` from the below array. We can do it like below

```
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var index = array.indexOf(3);

var d = array.splice(index, 1);
console.log(d);     // returns [3]
console.log(array); // returns [2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: May I know what is the significance of 1 which is the second parameter of splice().I couldnt find out about it-@PalaSH

Comment: @Techy: The last param indicates an integer indicating the number of old array elements you want to remove. If that number is 0, no elements are removed. In this case we just want to remove one element, so it would be removed.

Comment: @Techy: Cool. I have also added a demo example for reference.